# MFA_WEB_PKG_SIGNATURE_VERIFICATION_FAILED error during Yodlee Fastlink 2.0 integration in Android application

Tags: android, yodlee

I built the [sample](https://developer.yodlee.com/Fastlink_2.0) of Fastlink 2.0 Android application provided by Yodlee. I tried to log in, but without any success. Then I understood, that I should provide my own URLs and my own users' credentials, and I changed the `URL_RSESSION` value in `ProjectConstants` class. But now I receive a `MFAError errorMsg` with the following fields when logging in:

```
String a = "Unkown error"
String b = "MFA_UNKNOWN_ERROR"
MFAErrorCode c = "MFA_WEB_PKG_SIGNATURE_VERIFICATION_FAILED"
```

And I really don't know the reason, because there isn't any documentation which I can use during Fastlink 2.0 integration.
Maybe anybody knows what is this error about?..

Answer (score 0):

One of the below might be the reason for your error :

1. Webpkg might be opened and modified and again zipped, so the signature which was generated will not match.
2. Might be using old webpkg

Suggestion is to use the latest sample and try again.